# How can search and replace strings in vim and emacs be configured to work on partial or inexact matches?

Tags: regex, replace, partial-matches

I need to search and replace on strings which are partial matches and I have a **contrived** example below. The example below is the html from a help guide that I want to copy to add my own web page.

```
Open Link
Open Link in Background Tab
Upload Link
Open Link in Foreground Tab
Open Link in New Window
Download Link
Open Link in Incognito Window
```

Assuming I want to put the information in a Markdown or Asciidoctor table, requiring `|` before the lines beginning with for `Open` and append `|` after them, but ignore the other lines ie those starting with `Upload` and `Download`

How would I construct the search and replace string so it would only operate on the lines beginning with `Open`? Inserting `|` would be straightforward, but doing for the `$` regex for appending `|` only for the lines starting with `Open` would be the problem.

Is it also possible to do a search and replace on both sides at one go, ie do the insert and append in a single command, or would that require a script of some kind ?(I can make this a separate question)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Isn't this just `:%s/^Open.*/|&|/`?

Comment: @melpomene You mean that the `&` symbol equates to the matched string and everything around it goes to the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s/^\(Open.*\)/|\1|/
```

The \( and \) enclose a pattern match to be remembered (you can have more than one \( and \) in the match pattern), and the \1 in the replacement text uses the remembered text.

Comment: You can just use `&` in the replacement part. No need for capturing anything.

Comment: & is fine if you want to use the entire matched string, but \\( \\) allows you to collect multiple parts of the same string.